# Grails REST with g:form

Tags: rest, grails, put

How can I trigger a PUT(action update) method using a grails g:form.

I have tried something like this but it seems that the id of an instance to update is not send.

```
 <g:form name="updateForm" controller='book' id="${book.id}" method="PUT", >
 <g:field name ="uid" id ="inputForm" type="text" readOnly="true" value="${book.uid}">  </g:field > </br>
 <g:field  name ="description" id ="inputForm" type="text" value="${book.description}"></g:field > </br>
 <g:field  name="acessionNumber" id ="inputForm" type="text" value="${book.accessionNumber}"></g:field></br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
        </g:form>
```

uid, description and acessionNumber are all properties of a book

Or if my form my question differently. How can I send data to grails controller defined by rest from  my views?